# Time cost of training with pytorch DDP with multi-GPUs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-system

I use DDP of pytorch to train my model with two RTX3090 GPUs on a same machine, and I found the time cost is over than training without DDP on a single GPU. It costs about 133s to train my model with DDP while it costs 105s to train it without DDP per epoch. The data is correctly loaded into memory of the two GPUs. It seems that when using PyTorch's DistributedDataParallel (DDP) for training, the two GPUs did not perform parallel computing. Instead, the same task was computed twice.

My main code is as below:

```
import argparse
import os
import pickle
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
import time
from pathlib import Path
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from dataset.dataset_DPT import VQAFeatureDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from m3ae.modules import M3AETransformerSS
import torch.distributed as dist
import numpy as np
from dataset.tools import Logger, create_dir, set_schedule
import torch.nn.functional as F


@torch.no_grad()
def evaluation(model, data_loader, device):
    # test
    score = 0
    open_ended = 0
    closed_ended = 0
    open_score = 0
    close_score = 0
    stage1_dict = []
    # model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_mlm.pth'))
    model.eval()

    header = 'Generate VQA test result:'
    with torch.no_grad():
        for index, batch in enumerate(data_loader):
            batch['image'][0] = batch['image'][0].to(device)
            batch['text_ids'] = batch['text_ids'].to(device)
            batch['text_labels'] = batch['text_labels'].to(device)
            batch['text_ids_mlm'] = batch['text_ids_mlm'].to(device)
            batch['text_labels_mlm'] = batch['text_labels_mlm'].to(device)
            batch['text_masks'] = batch['text_masks'].to(device)

            target_list = []
            for l in range(len(batch['vqa_labels'])):
                target_list.append(batch['vqa_labels'][l].unsqueeze(0))
            targets = torch.cat(target_list, dim=0).to(device)

            target = torch.argmax(targets, dim=1)
            ans_type = batch['answer_types']
            phrase_type = batch['phrase_type']

            logits = model(batch)


            values, indices = torch.topk(logits, k=8, dim=-1)
            values = values.detach().cpu().numpy()
            indices = indices.detach().cpu().numpy()
            for i in range(values.shape[0]):
                stage1_dict.append((indices[i].astype(np.int16), values[i].astype(np.float16)))

            pred_score = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)

            for i in range(len(ans_type)):
                if ans_type[i] == 'OPEN':
                    open_ended += 1
                    if target[i] == pred_score[i]:
                        open_score += 1
                elif ans_type[i] == 'CLOSED':
                    closed_ended += 1
                    if target[i] == pred_score[i]:
                        close_score += 1

        score += open_score + close_score
    # with open('data/vqa/data_RAD/stage1_train.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
    #     pickle.dump(stage1_dict, fp)
    score = (score / (open_ended + closed_ended))
    open_score = (open_score / open_ended)
    close_score = (close_score / closed_ended)

    return score, open_score, close_score

def main(args, config):



    create_dir('outputs')
    logger = Logger('outputs/log.txt')
    logger.write(args.__repr__())
    # device = torch.device(args.device)

    if args.local_rank != -1:
        torch.cuda.set_device(args.local_rank)
        device = torch.device("cuda", args.local_rank)
        torch.distributed.init_process_group(backend="nccl")


    trainset = VQAFeatureDataset('train')
    testset = VQAFeatureDataset('test')


    # tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(args.text_encoder)

    #### Creating Model ####
    print("Creating model")
    config['load_path'] = '/home/liyong/PythonWorkspace/M3AE-vqa/checkpoints/m3ae.ckpt'
    # config['load_path'] = ''

    model = M3AETransformerSS(config)
    model = model.to(device)

    num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
    if num_gpus > 1:
        print('use {} gpus!'.format(num_gpus))
        model = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[args.local_rank],
                                                    output_device=args.local_rank, find_unused_parameters=True)
    word_size = dist.get_world_size()
    train_sampler = DistributedSampler(trainset, num_replicas=word_size, rank=args.local_rank)
    train_loader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=config['batch_size'], num_workers=4, sampler=train_sampler,
                              collate_fn=trainset.collote)

    test_loader = DataLoader(testset, batch_size=config['batch_size'], num_workers=4, collate_fn=testset.collote,
                             shuffle=False)

    optimizer, scheduler = set_schedule(model, config, len(trainset.entries))

    # print(model)
    # score, open_score, close_score = evaluation(model, test_loader, device)
    best_score = 0
    best_epoch = 0
    for epoch in range(config['max_epoch']):
        train_sampler.set_epoch(epoch)

        strat_time = time.time()
        print(f"Start running basic DDP example on rank {args.local_rank}.")

        total_loss = 0

        for index, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
            batch['image'][0] = batch['image'][0].to(device)
            batch['text_ids'] = batch['text_ids'].to(device)
            batch['text_labels'] = batch['text_labels'].to(device)
            batch['text_ids_mlm'] = batch['text_ids_mlm'].to(device)
            batch['text_labels_mlm'] = batch['text_labels_mlm'].to(device)
            batch['text_masks'] = batch['text_masks'].to(device)

            target_list = []
            for l in range(len(batch['vqa_labels'])):
                target_list.append(batch['vqa_labels'][l].unsqueeze(0))
            targets = torch.cat(target_list, dim=0).to(device)
            logits = model(batch)
            # loss = criterion(logits.float(), targets)
            loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits.float(), targets)
            total_loss += loss
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()

        end_time = time.time()

        if args.local_rank == 0:
            score, open_score, close_score = evaluation(model, test_loader, device)

            logger.write('epoch ========== %d' % (epoch))
            logger.write('overall: %.4f,  open: %.4f,  close: %.4f,   loss: %.4f,   lr: %.6f, time: %.4f'
                         % (score, open_score, close_score, total_loss, optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr'], end_time-strat_time))

            if score > best_score:
                torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), '/home/liyong/PythonWorkspace/M3AE-vqa/model_mlm_ddp.pth')
                best_epoch = epoch
                best_score = score

                # print("best_score ======= " + str(round(best_score, 4)) + "  best_epoch ======= " + str(best_epoch))
            logger.write('best_score: %.4f,      best_epoch: %d' % (best_score, best_epoch))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--config', default='/home/liyong/PythonWorkspace/M3AE-vqa/configs/RAD_M3AE.yaml')
    # parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', default='./pretrain/2022-09-11/med_pretrain_29.pth')
    parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--output_dir', default='/home/liyong/PythonWorkspace/M3AE-vqa/output/rad')
    parser.add_argument('--evaluate', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--text_encoder', default='bert-base-uncased')
    parser.add_argument('--text_decoder', default='bert-base-uncased')
    parser.add_argument('--device', type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', default=42, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--world_size', default=1, type=int, help='number of distributed processes')
    parser.add_argument('--dist_url', default='env://', help='url used to set up distributed training')
    parser.add_argument('--distributed', default=False, type=bool)
    parser.add_argument("--local_rank", default=os.getenv('LOCAL_RANK', -1), type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    config = yaml.load(open(args.config, 'r'), Loader=yaml.Loader)

    config['image_size'] = 224
    config['tokenizer'] = 'roberta-base'

    args.result_dir = os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'result')

    Path(args.output_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path(args.result_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # yaml.dump(config, open(os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'config.yaml'), 'w'))

    print("config: ", config)
    print("args: ", args)
    main(args, config)
```

I use the following command to execute my main code:

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=2 DPT_MLM_ddp2.py
```

Some output log during training is as below

[image: OutputScreenshot]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, thanks!